# Three.js Calculate the Area of Geometry Face (Face3)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am exporting a 3D model with the ColladaLoader, every Mesh create a Geometry object with multiple Faces.

I manage to select faces to change colors and textures of a single face that is an array of Triangles (Face3).
[image: Change color of single face of a Mesh]

[image: Change texture of single face of a Mesh]

Know I need to get the area of each "Face" I know the faces are a sum of Triangles instances of Face3. I try looping through each related face and summing the **a, b and c** values like this, but with no luck.

```
var sAB = Math.abs(face.a - face.b);
var sBC = Math.abs(face.b - face.c);
var sCA = Math.abs(face.c - face.a);
var s = sAB + sBC + sCA;
var a = Math.sqrt(s*(s-sAB)*(s-sBC)*(s-sCA));
```

How can a calculate the Area of a Face3 triangle object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values `a`, `b` and `c` of the Face3 do not store the actual vertices. Instead, the indices of the vertices in `geometry.vertices` are stored there. So to retrieve the three vertices you need something like this:

```
var va = geometry.vertices[face.a];
var vb = geometry.vertices[face.b];
var vc = geometry.vertices[face.c];
```

The calculations you are using do not work that way when dealing with vectors. You need to use the functions from [`THREE.Vector3`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Vector3) (for instance `var v = new THREE.Vector3(); v.subVectors(va, vb);`) to do these calculations.

Alternatively, there is a class [`THREE.Triangle`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/math/Triangle) that you can use for that:

```
var t = new THREE.Triangle(va,vb,vc);
var area = t.getArea();
```

Comment: :D Double shot with `THREE.Triangle()`

Comment: Thanks to both it works like a charm, I'll give the point to Martin who answered first . EDIT - I upvote you both

Comment: This answer is great but wont work for a buffer geometry. To calculate the faces and vertices of a buffer geometry take a look here: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-get-faces-triangle-data-from-buffergeometry/22906/2

Answer (score 3):

You can use `THREE.Triangle()` and its [`.getArea()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/math/Triangle.getArea) method:

```js
var geom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);

var face0 = geom.faces[0]; // you know what face, you want to get its area

var verts = geom.vertices;

var tri = new THREE.Triangle(verts[face0.a], verts[face0.b], verts[face0.c]);

var area = tri.getArea();
console.log(area);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other two answers, mathematically, if you do a cross product of two vectors, the length of the resulting vector will be twice the area you are looking for. In three.js speak:

```
new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(
 new THREE.Vector3().subVectors( vertexB, vertexA ),
 new THREE.Vector3().subVectors( vertexC, vertexA ),
).length() / 2
```

Comment: Yeah, `THREE.Triangle()` uses exactly the same [approach](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/35ae830a7c4544582ed2759e5b18c5d6ef37c6d9/src/math/Triangle.js#L153) :) (It's a pity that I can upvote just once :) )

Answer (score 2):

[THREE.ShapeUtils](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/ShapeUtils) comes with a convenience method [`getArea`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/ShapeUtils.area) where you pass an array of points/vertices of a 2D polygon:

> *.area* ( contour ) : Number
>
> contour -- 2D polygon.
>
> Calculate area of a ( 2D ) contour polygon.

This method more or less the same as in @pailhead his answer but works for a polygon with several points instead of only three points (a triangle).

To be able to use this for vertices that are not in the X-Y plane (from a 3D mesh) you would need to rotate/project your mesh first so it ends up in the X-Y plane. You can easily do that with a rotation matrix.

---

**Note:** Be aware that this method uses a method that comes with limitations for self-intersecting polygons. Check also [the Limitations chapter on this "Math Open Reference" page](https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html) for reference.